# Azure Function : How do I write my logs to Azure Application Insights using local debug mode with Azure Functions using Python?

Tags: python, logging, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-application-insights

I want to write my logs to the Azure Application Insights but I do not know how to achieve it.
Do I need to update my azure function **local.settings.json** and **host.json** file ??
Also, do I need to use call specific function in ****init**.py** file to write my logs to Azure Application Insights?
Can you please share some examples to write logs.
Please note- I am using python for my Azure function.
Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is the host.json:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "logging": {
        "applicationInsights": {
            "samplingSettings": {
                "isEnabled": true,
                "excludedTypes": "Request"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the official settings:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json#applicationinsights

'applicationInsights.samplingSettings.isEnabled' is to Enables or disables sampling.

Comment: The same configuration got generated at the time of function creation. Do I need to add anything else such as loglevel etc?? Also, if I debug the application from my local system then How would it get know know that where to write the logs.

Comment: possibly I need to add key to the local.settings.json. "APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY": "<mykey>"

Comment: can you please tell me that how do I write the logs to app insights. merely writing the following logger would work?? `logging.info('-----------main function starts-----------')` and
`logging.exception("Error occured in main")`

Comment: @Stark Yes. 'logging.info' 'logging.exception' should be able to write the logs to app insights. But it will not send to app insights immediately. It will take few minutes.